# Set up Microsoft DNS to redirect domain to the web server

Tags: dns

I have set up a Active Directory with the name aaa.bbb.mycompany.com
So fare everything is fine. But I also want that when the users use the URL aaa.bbb.mycompany.com in the web browser, they come to our web server. The problem is that the DNS is mapping that domain to DNS server and not the web server. How do I redirect it to the web server?

Edit:

The domain aaa.bbb.mycompany.com is the root in my configuration and it have a two way trust with mycompany.com

The configuration in the DNS:
aaa.bbb.mycompany.com   NS    ad01.aaa.bbb.mycompany.com
aaa.bbb.mycompany.com   NS    ad02.aaa.bbb.mycompany.com
aaa.bbb.mycompany.com   A     xxx.xxx.xxx.136
aaa.bbb.mycompany.com   A     xxx.xxx.xxx.135
ad01                    A     xxx.xxx.xxx.136
ad02                    A     xxx.xxx.xxx.135
web01                   A     xxx.xxx.xxx.134

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like DNS is pointing aaa.bbb.mycompany.com to the IP address of the DNS server instead of the web server, to fix that you just need to modify the DNS records to point to the correct location.

You've got Active Directory installed so I'll assume you're using the Windows DNS role which installs with it by default. Open the DNS console and under Forward Lookup Zones you should see a zone for your active directoy domain (probably mycompany.com), edit the A record for aaa.bbb.mycompany.com so that it points to the correct IP address of your web server.

The DNS record for aaa.bbb.mycompany.com may be set up as a CNAME which points to a host A record so you may instead have to update the A record that aaa.bbb.mycompany.com is pointing to.

Depending on DNS caching and TTL values that you have set the change may take some time to propagate. In the DNS console you can right click the server name on the left and type clear cache, this will purge the DNS servers cache. On the client computer that is loading aaa.bbb.mycompany.com up through web browser in command prompt you can run "ipconfig /flushdns" to clear client side cache.